# Power calculation by simulation - what do I do with model failures?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation, statistical-power, nonlinear

I'm trying to run a power calculation by simulation on a set of exponential decay datasets using the nlme package in R. Here's the process:

- Simulate a bunch of exponentials, using some conservative parameters with a small effect size and some noise
- Run a nonlinear mixed effects model 1000 times each at different sample sizes, and record p-value
- Calculate the fraction of models that have a significant decay coefficient at significance level of 0.05

However, one small issue: sometimes the model fails to run in R, generally due to convergence issues. There's a few different errors that I'm encountering. Every time the model fails I simply rerun it until the model runs correctly.

My question is: should I be including the model failures in my denominator when I calculate power?

Option 1: power = significant/(significant + not_significant)

Option 2: power = significant/(significant + not_significant + model_failures)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my strategy was wrong in the first place - I was trying to fit a mixed effects model with too many random effects. By simplifying the model I was able to get the Option 1 and Option 2 power calculations to converge.